# How do I do a Django query filter that matches against a list of values?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Hey guys I'm doing a small social media app and right now I'm having trouble figuring out how to display the posts of users someone is following.  Right now I create a list that adds all of the usernames to it as values.  How can I filter out the Django query results where it prints out all the results of those contained in the list?

I can do it where it prints out only one of the followers posts, since I can compare one value easily. But how can I do the same when I need to compare to a list of values?  Any ideas?  Thanks guys.

Below is my code:

```
def follows(request, username):
# create list
list = []
# get the username of the signed in user
userSearch = User.objects.get(username = username)
# get the user ID of the signed in user
userID = userSearch.id
# get the user IDs of the followers of the signed in user
query = Follow.objects.filter(follower_id = userID)
#get the usernames of the followers of the signed in user
query2 = User.objects.filter(id = query[0].following_id)
#add the usernames to a list
for i in query:
    list.append(i.username)

query3 = NewPost.objects.filter(username = query2[0].username)
paginator = Paginator(query3, 10)
page_number = request.GET.get('page')
page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
return render(request, "network/follows.html", { "page_obj": page_obj })
```

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
    
class Follow(models.Model):
    follower_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    following_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class NewPost(models.Model):
    userID = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="")
    body = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Share your models.

Comment: please make use of `ForeignKey`s instead of `IntegerField`s (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey). This will enforce integrity at the database and make querying simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that on my next project but I don't feel like restarting everything on this one. Security is not an issue just functionality. Thank you.

Comment: it is not only security. With `ForeignKey`s, you can easily write queries like `NewPost.objects.filter(user__following__follower=request.user)`, this will thus make `JOIN`s at the database making it not only more efficient, but a lot more elegant. You thus can make use of a *one-liner* to retrieve all `NewPost`s published by a person followed by a user.

Comment: is there no way to do it currently?

Answer (score 3):

I used this code to do exactly what I needed.

```
query3 = NewPost.objects.filter(userID__in = list)
```